# Why some of the tables output data in primary key ASC but some not without specifying the order?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

If I don't specify by what order should the data be output, what's the order mysql output data? What's the factor? Why some of them are ASC but some are DESC judging by their PK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no order without the outermost ORDER BY.

- A table is just a set of records and sets have no order
- Any pattern you see is arbitrary, not reliable and not repeatable

Comment: What do you mean by 'arbitrary'? If it is arbitrary why the result is always the same if I don't set an order?

Comment: @LotusH: it's arbitrary. Pure and simple. If you backup/restore to another system, or delete and re-add a row the order will most likely change. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by_(SQL) which says "ORDER BY is the only way to sort the rows in the result set"